# MySQLi error when inserting

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

I have a problem. When I want to insert in mysql table from php it doesn't work and it write an error

```
Unknown column 'pass' in 'field list'
```

I tried delete and create entire table through php and it works.

When I try the same query in phpMyAdmin, it works.

My php is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(login,name,surname,pass,city,street,email,cardnr,zip,phone) VALUES('".$login."','".$name."','".$surname."','".$pass."','".$city."','".$street."','".$mail."','".$card."','".$zip."','".$phone."')";
$this->link->query($sql);
```

Please help me, thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query at first glance. However PHPMYAdmin does change queries a bit before executing, could you post what PHPMyAdmin executed? (it is adbove the result screen)

Comment: You appear to be using a framework. If that's the case, why are you writing out the queries instead of using the interface the framework gives you for database interaction?

Comment: Maybe you are using another database where the column doesn't exist, in your php code.

Comment: php echoed query INSERT INTO users(login,name,surname,pass,city,street,email,cardnr,zip,phone) VALUES('test','test','test','70c881d4a26984ddce795f6f71817c9cf4480e79','test','abcd 12','test@test.test','123456789012','01234','0123456789') and phpmyadmin executed query INSERT INTO users( login, name, surname, pass, city, street, email, cardnr, zip, phone )
VALUES (
'test', 'test', 'test', '70c881d4a26984ddce795f6f71817c9cf4480e79', 'test', 'abcd 12', 'test@test.test', '123456789012', '01234', '0123456789'
)  DB is correct, I don't use framework

Comment: ok I tried delete and create entire table and php and it works. thanx everyone for trying help

Answer (score 0):

you table `users` doesn't contain a `pass` column.

The error message is pretty self-explanatory, you should check your spelling of the column name.

Otherwise, are you sure you're working on the same database with PHPMyAdmin and your PHP code ?

Comment: Yes it does. And I have written that the same query works in phpmyadmin

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit, and no, the message is really clear about this, there's not column `pass` in your table.

Comment: yes I am working with the same db, and that column really exists in that table. I've copied name of column from phpmyadmin and pasted into my php, so it is there

Comment: Ok, so tell MySQL to stop lying, and everything should work just fine :)

Comment: Try printing the description of the table on your application. `DESC users;`

Comment: Field  Type  Null  Key  Default  Extra   id  int(11)  NO  PRI  NULL  auto_increment
   login  varchar(255)  NO     NULL   
   name  varchar(255)  NO     NULL   
   surname  varchar(255)  NO     NULL   
   pass  varchar(40)  NO     NULL   
  city  varchar(255)  NO     NULL   
   street  varchar(255)  NO     NULL   
   email  varchar(255)  NO     NULL   
   cardnr  varchar(255)  NO     NULL   
   zip  int(5)  NO     NULL   
   auth  varchar(5)  NO     USER   
  phone  varchar(10)  NO     NULL

Comment: Try changing the column name... / Intenta cambiando el nombre de la columna?

Answer (score 0):

try encapsulating all field names with ` (backtik)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Thor - If there was, I would give a "grave digger" badge. This is ages ago. Besides. The way I wrote it looks like a suggestion, but, it is actually the answer...In which case, you are welcome to edit it.